# How to add expires to flutter web cookie?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using [document.cookie](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.22.0/dart-html/Document/cookie.html) to store cookie in my web app. i want to add 'expires' parameter and set expire after 30 days.
how can i do this.

```
  void _addToCookie(String key, String value) {
    document.cookie = "$key=$value;expires=30";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "max-age" parameter instead of "expires".
"max-age" requires seconds ;max-age=max-age-in-seconds (e.g., 60*60*24*365 or 31536000 for a year)

for 30 days 30×24×60×60 = 2592000.

```
 void _addToCookie(String key, String value) {
    document.cookie = "$key=$value; max-age=2592000;";
  }
```